# Magento Fatal Error - setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, php-5.4

I tried to create an admin grid on magento.Get the error while click on the admin menu **setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object**.

**My Config.xml** : path(\app\code\local\ORD\UpdatePro\etc)

```
<admin>
 <routers>
     <updatepro>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
           <module>ORD_UpdatePro</module>
           <frontName>admintest</frontName>
        </args>
     </updatepro>
  </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
   <layout>
      <updates>
          <updatepro>
              <file>updatepro.xml</file>
           </updatepro>
      </updates>
   </layout>
   <menu>
      <updatepro translate="title" module="adminhtml">
         <title>updatepro</title>
         <sort_order>100</sort_order>
         <children>
             <set_time>
                   <title>Report</title>
                   <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                   <action>admintest/adminhtml_index</action>
              </set_time>

          </children>
       </updatepro>
   </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

My **IndexController.php** : Path(\app\code\local\ORD\UpdatePro\controllers\Adminhtml)

```
class ORD_UpdatePro_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
protected function _initAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('updatepro/set_time')
            ->_addBreadcrumb('updatepro Manager','updatepro Manager');
   return $this;
 }
//END of initaction
public function indexAction()
  {
     $this->_initAction();
     $this->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

My Block Class **Grid.php** : Path(\app\code\local\ORD\UpdatePro\Block\Adminhtml)

```
class ORD_UpdatePro_Block_Adminhtml_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{ 
  public function __construct(){
     $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_grid';
     $this->_blockGroup = 'updatepro';
     $this->_headerText = 'Adressbook management';
     $this->_addButtonLabel = 'Add a contact';
     parent::__construct();
 }
}
```

My Layout file **updatepro.xml** : Path(\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <layout version="0.1.0">
   <updatepro_adminhtml_index_index>
     <reference name="content">
      <block type="updatepro/adminhtml_grid"  name="updatepro" template="updatepro/afficher.phtml" />
    </reference>
   </updatepro_adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
```

while click on the admin panel menu link i got the below error message

**Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\staging_furryfriends\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Container.php on line 69**

it was a common error and found in many threads, Followed every steps carefully, unfortunately i am unable to figure out the problem and what was the error.
Expecting your kind explanation if any one can help me on this topic.

Comment: add $this->_addButtonLabel using helper: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-setsaveparametersinsession-on-a-non-object/

Comment: Thank you, $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_mynewgrid'; your changes are on this line.i used this  $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_grid';according to me its right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [How to create a custom grid from scratch][1] and [custom module with custom database table](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

Grid.php : Incorrect and missing

```
class <Namespace>_<Module>_Block_Adminhtml_<Module> extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_<module>';
        $this->_blockGroup = '<module>';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('<module>')->__('Item Manager');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('<module>')->__('Add Item');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}


class <Namespace>_<Module>_Block_Adminhtml_<Module>_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('<module>Grid');
        // This is the primary key of the database
        $this->setDefaultSort('<module>_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Clear answer and now its working and got an idea.
one more question to my understanding.. the second class which extends the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid also in the same class?

Comment: can you pls help me in this question.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51957/adding-extra-fields-to-newsletter-subscriber-table-not-work

Answer (score 7):

Have a look on the error to which Magento refers.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild( 'grid',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
        $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Here the function that holds `setSaveParametersInSession()` is `_prepareLayout()`. This function is processed during layout preparation time carried out by magento. If you have a closer look on the method, you will understand that, it is triying to set a child block to grid block that you have defined via layout file (`$this` stands for the grid block).

In case of admin grid block, actually we just defines the outer block of grid in our layout file. Magento then set a child block to this grid block and then use it for its internally in order to generate the entire grid section. So the collection that we set in grid block, will then use by this child block and will process accordingly. Why Magento generates child blocks programmatically ? This is because, almost all time, magento admin grid looks same . Only the collection that loading in that grid changes. So Magento allows us to `_prepareCollection()` in our custom grid block so that it the entire grid page uses our custom collection. You dont need to do any complex thing in order to generate the complex grid structure.

Now I want your concenration on this code

```
 createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid', $this->_controller . '.grid')
```

***this is what become an invalid object in your context***. As you can see it tries to generate a block. As per the definition inside your grid block (`ORD_UpdatePro_Block_Adminhtml_Grid`. this is a wrong class actually. I come to this point later), this code can be rewrite like this.

```
 createBlock('updatepro/adminhtml_grid_grid', 'adminhtml_grid.grid')
```

The first argument stands for `type` of the block and second argurment stands for `name` of the newly generating block. The type of your block means, Magento will look for `ORD_UpdatePro_Block_Adminhtml_Grid_Grid` block class inside your module. Unfortunately Magento cannot found out that class because, that class really not exist. So magento complaints it.

Actually the block that should generate in this context is `ORD_UpdatePro_Block_Adminhtml_Updatepro_Grid` (As per the best practices) and I hope you have that file is actually defined inside your module at `app/code/local/RD/UpdatePro/Block/Adminhtml/Updatepro/Grid.php`.

Now let us look how can we generate this name inside your grid container block. Oh wait. Your grid block seems wrong. It should be `ORD_UpdatePro_Block_Adminhtml_UpdatePro` instead of `ORD_UpdatePro_Block_Adminhtml_Grid`. But block that you defined now is  recognizing by Magento. That is why the error itself is raised!!! So let us look why it is recognized. In your layout file, you have this.

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="updatepro/adminhtml_grid"  name="updatepro" template="updatepro/afficher.phtml" />
</reference>
```

The block that you including here is `ORD_UpdatePro_Block_Adminhtml_Grid`. So magento is able to recognize your block, because it is defined backend of your module. However as per the best practice, it is wrong. Your layout should looks like this.

```
 <reference name="content">
  <block type="updatepro/adminhtml_updatepro"  name="updatepro" template="updatepro/afficher.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Now your block points to the block `ORD_UpdatePro_Block_Adminhtml_UpdatePro` and it should defined at `app/code/local/ORD/UpdatePro/Block/Adminhtml/UpdatePro.php`.

Inside this you need to look on below property values which is actually using to generate child grid block as I explained before.

```
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_updatepro';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'updatepro';
```

Now as per the definition of this private properties, the function in question will look like this.

```
createBlock('updatepro/adminhtml_update_grid', 'adminhtml_updatepro.grid')
```

and this eventually looks for the block `ORD_UpdatePro_Block_Adminhtml_Updatepro_Grid`. If you have this block is defined at the backside of your module (`app/code/local/RD/UpdatePro/Block/Adminhtml/Updatepro/Grid.php`), then everything is super cool. No confusion for us and no confusion for magento. Story should have a happy endings then !!!

### What is the big point?

Beware this private properties. `$this->_blockGroup` and `$this->_controller`.

> `$this->_blockGroup` should be the block alias name that you have specified insid your module's config.xml file. In normal case it will looks like `[namespace]_[modulename]`
>   `$this->_controller` should be the trailing block paths that is pointing towards your `grid container` block.  In normal case it would be `adminhtml_[modulename]`

Comment: Thank you for the attempt to help me.
i refer this link(http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-admin-gridview-85) to understand the grid view.i tried with several tutorials but still i am unable to view the grid.Do you have any tutorials regarding this admin grid view.
i tried with this too.http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0__module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Comment: Show us your module and i am happy to help u

Comment: Thank you.In which way i can Show my code.can i have your email id to send or what other ways.if i overcome this it will be great help

Comment: Please come to this room for further discussion http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18757/discussion-between-programmer-rkt-and-mujas

Comment: unable to come to room.need some more reputation to continue in room.

Comment: unable to come to room.need some more reputation to continue in room.Sure i will Ask a new question.unable to reply you in the room.

Comment: ok can you raise new question with following files. config.xml, layout xml file of your module, block files upto grid.php. PLease put a new question with these details and we are happy to help you.

Comment: yes after asking a new question, ping me here. I will have a look on the issue

Comment: i asked this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44454/admin-grid-view-for-magento-not-workcustom-module-with-custom-database-table

Comment: Hi, Hope you can help me in this question .
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50054/how-to-update-sales-flat-order-table-status-column-by-checking-the-payment-metho

Comment: can you pls help me in this question.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51957/adding-extra-fields-to-newsletter-subscriber-table-not-work

Comment: nice. @RajeevKTomy