# How to update sales_flat_order table status column by checking the payment method choose by the customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, sales, order-status, status

I created a new status on admin panel for orders.

```
System -> order status -> create new status
```

I created the status for cash on delivery payment option.

While the order processing, how can i track the payment method and update the table `sales_flat_order`
`status` column   with cash on delivery as status.
My status code is `cod`

Comment: are want assign the order status code to CASH on delivery orders

Comment: yes i want to check the payment method and if the method selected by the customer is cash on delivery then only i want to update the sales_flat_order table's status in to cod which i already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mujas,you can do this by magento event observer.

`Fire` an `observer` on event  `checkout_submit_all_after` and change order status your New Order status.

**event Config.xml code look like**

```
<global>
    <events>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <change_order_status>
                    <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>CodeOrdeStatus</method>
                </change_order_status>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Observer code look like:

```
public function CodeOrdeStatus($observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
    // check order is code or not
    if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == "cashondelivery") {
        $order->setStatus("complete");
        $order->save();    
    }
}
```

Comment: @Amith Bera Thank you for your time,I will try and update the status

Comment: I worked on your idea.For the completeness of the answer i have to Create main module xml file also.
and this line 
if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="cod"):
the payment method should be "cashondelivery" instead of "cod".
for future users easy i just mention here add the <events> tag in to <global> tag in your config.xml file.
Thanks Amith Bera You save my time.

Comment: Hi Amith, glad if you can help me in this question.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51957/adding-extra-fields-to-newsletter-subscriber-table-not-work