# Create a Store Config value, its not saved and unable to retrieve the value

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, configuration, adminhtml

Following are the steps for creating store config value.I created this fields for store some shipping value and add that value in to total in the checkout page.

**STEP 01**
**config.xml file :- Path(app\code\local\Wired\Concept\etc)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Wired_Concept>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wired_Concept>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <concept>
            <class>Wired_Concept_Model</class>
        </concept>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <concept>
            <class>Wired_Concept_Helper</class>
        </concept>
    </helpers>
 </global>
 <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <wired>
                                        <title>Wired Consept - All</title>
                                    </wired>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

**STEP 02 system.xml file :- Path(app\code\local\Wired\Concept\etc)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <wired translate="label" module="concept">
        <label>Wired Extensions</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </wired>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <wired translate="label" module="concept">
        <label>Extension Options</label>
        <tab>wired</tab>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <wired_group translate="label" module="concept">
                <label>Shipping &amp; Handling Charge</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <wired_shipping_charge translate="label">
                        <label>Shipping &amp; Handling Charge : </label>
                        <comment>Shipping &amp; handling charge for entire order</comment>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </wired_shipping_charge>                        
                </fields>
            </wired_group>              
        </groups>           
    </wired>
</sections>
</config>
```

**STEP 03 create the Wired_Concept.xml file :- Path(\app\etc\modules)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Wired_Concept>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Wired_Concept>
</modules>
```

**STEP 04 helper class Data.php :- Path(\app\code\local\Wired\Concept\Helper)**

```
<?php
class Wired_Concept_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
/* Shipping charge for whole order*/
public function config_shipping(){
return Mage::getStoreConfig('wired/wired_group/wired_shipping_charge');
}
}
```

In the admin panel the text field is shown under wired extension.I try to get value using

```
echo Mage::helper('concept')->config_shipping_cost();
```

no any value retrieve for me and also in the admin panel the value saved also not retrieve n the created text filed.

I am unable to verify my mistakes to unsaved the value and nor retrieve the value which i saved using the text field i created.
It will be a great pleasure to help me to identify my issue.

Comment: your helper function is config_shipping and you was try to fetch data using ->config_shipping_cost();

Comment: thank you @AmitBera. earlier i kept it as config_shipping and later change to config_shipping_cost.I want to clarify with you is "config_shipping" is a default magento function?

Comment: no...config_shipping_cost()  not a  default function

Comment: thank you very much.I asked another question 3 days back didn't get any answer shall i forward it here for your consideration?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50054/how-to-update-sales-flat-order-table-status-column-by-checking-the-payment-metho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your helper function is `config_shipping` and you was try to fetch data using -`config_shipping_cost()` So Pleas try this

```
 Mage::helper('concept')->config_shipping();
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50054/how-to-update-sales-flat-order-table-status-column-by-checking-the-payment-metho