# Adding extra fields to newsletter_subscriber table not work

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, event-observer, newsletter

I try to add a type(extra field) to `newsletter_subscriber` table.

Following is my approach to add the field.

**1.Add new column to newsletter_subscriber table(types)**

**2.Add types check box to subscribe.phtml file**

**3.Create an observer for newsletter_subscriber_save_before event**

My `Config.xml` file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Wired_Newsletters>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wired_Newsletters>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <newsletters>
            <class>Wired_Newsletters_Model</class>
        </newsletter>
    </models>
    <events>
        <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
            <observers>
                <newsletters_add_types>
                    <class>newsletters/observer</class>
                    <method>newsletterSubscriberSave</method>
                </newsletters_add_types>
            </observers>
        </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
    </events>
 </global>
```

My `observer.php` file(\app\code\local\Wired\Newsletters\Model)

```
<?php
class Wired_Newsletters_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
public function newsletterSubscriberSave($observer){
    $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
    $types = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('types');

    $subscriber->setTypes($types);
    //$subscriber->save();
    return $this;
    }
}
```

**Did i miss any steps or my approach is wrong and please advice me how can i check the process is in the relevant observer?**
**Is there any alternative solution add an extra field to  `newsletter_subscriber` table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model ending is wrong:

```
<models>
        <newsletters>
            <class>Wired_Newsletters_Model</class>
        </newsletters> <!-- it should be newsletters from newsletter -->
    </models>
```

According to magento your model idenfier and end start tags should be same

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <{module identifier}>
                <class>{class prefix}</class>
            </{module identifier}>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: thanks, it working.can you pls suggest me some debugging methods in magento.

Comment: I will.give u  detail shortu

Comment: Hi Amith, Its very http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51794/how-to-repeat-the-orders-with-n-number-of-products-in-the-order-times-in-magen if you can answer this question.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51794/how-to-repeat-the-orders-with-n-number-of-products-in-the-order-times-in-magen