# Adding a custom field to Magento Newsletter

Tags: newsletter

I'm trying to add a custom field to the Magento Newsletter.  The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155784/adding-a-custom-field-to-magentos-subscription-module) by Roman Snitko looks hopeful.  But I'm not sure how to create observer for  the **newsletter_subscriber_save_before** event.

So I googled and found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51957/adding-extra-fields-to-newsletter-subscriber-table-not-work) question, and based the following code off of that.  Am I missing a file or something to make the observer work?

/app/etc/modules/Custom_Newsletter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Newsletter>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Newsletter />
      </depends>
    </Custom_Newsletter>
  </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/community/Custom/Newsletter/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Newsletter>
      <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </Custom_Newsletter>
  </modules>
 <global>
    <models>
      <newsletters>
        <class>Custom_Newsletter_Model</class>
      </newsletters>
    </models>
    <events>
      <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
        <observers>
          <newsletters_add_types>
            <class>newsletters/observer</class>
            <method>newsletterSubscriberSave</method>
          </newsletters_add_types>
        </observers>
      </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/community/Custom/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

Mage::log('Observer method fired', null, 'newsletter.txt');

class Custom_Newsletter_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
  public function __construct(){
  }

  public function newsletterSubscriberSave($observer){
    $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
    $zone = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('zone');

    $subscriber->setZone($zone);

    //$subscriber->save();
    return $this;
  }
}
```

I have added an input[name=zone] in the view.  I have added a field [zone] the database.  There are no errors, but the data isn't saved.  If I added a `die()` into the `newsletterSubscriberSave` function, nothing happens.

**Edit:** Here is the form, in case something looks strange there:

```
<form action="http://sites.dev/en/newsletter/manage/save/" method="post" id="form-validate">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="xOMnfzMi8WfdZV5w">
        <h2 class="legend">Newsletter Subscription</h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="control"><input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" id="subscription" value="1" title="General Subscription" checked="checked" class="checkbox"><label for="subscription">General Subscription</label></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="back-link"><a href="http://sites.dev/en/customer/account/"><small>« </small>Back</a></p>
        <button type="submit" title="Save" class="button"><span><span>Save</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box" style="display:none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="zone" id="newsletter_zone" value="USA">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: donot need to use $subscriber->save();

Comment: Thanks.  I removed that, but no effect.  It's still not saving.  If I add a `die()` in the __construct, it still doesn't die, which makes me suspect that it's never getting as far as my observer.php

Comment: I have just tried it on a clean install and it worked first time. Are you sure you are not using any third party module, like MageMonkey, that could change the subscription route?

Comment: You should first make sure that the observer method is being called when the event is dispatched. To do that, just try writing to the log: ``Mage::log('Observer method fired', null, 'newsletter.txt');``. If you see that line you know your observer is being called.

Comment: I see that your file is named ``observer.php`` no caps. I've had problems before in a linux environment where a file had the wrong capitalization. I'm not sure but maybe Magento looks for ``Observer.php`` with a capital O. You could check that too.

Comment: @Mayers - Thank you so much for testing it!  I don't have MageMonkey installed, but it's not impossible that I have something changing the subscription route.  How would I check?

Comment: @Vic - Thanks!  I added Mage::log in my Observer.php file before the class, and nothing shows up in var/log/ (I have 777 permissions, so that shouldn't be a problem).  I have also renamed my file to Observer with a capital O.  So I guess it's my observer that's not getting called?

Comment: @Jonathan You should add the line to write to the log inside the method that is supposed to be called (``newsletterSubscriberSave``). Magento will load the class and then call the method, so nothing before the class will ever be run. Just comment out all the code inside ``newsletterSubscriberSave`` and leave the ``Mage::log`` line.

Comment: @Vic I moved the Mage::log into the function and commented out all the other code, and there is still nothing in var/log/newsletter.txt (which I created with permissions 777, just to be sure).  So I guess Magento is skipping my observer somehow?

Comment: That's weird. Specially since @Mayers tried it and it worked. Could it be that some other extension has registered an observer with the handle ``newsletters_add_types``? I can't come up with anything else. The config seems to be allright. Try changing the name of the handle to something more specific like ``custom_newsletters_add_zone``. (I just remembered that a coworker once lost almost a day of work figuring out a problem with the config file to find it was a space in the begining of the file like `` <?xml version= ..``)

Comment: I did a grep on my server, and there was no other use of `newsletters_add_types`.  Neverthless, I changed my handle as you suggested.  There is still nothing in the log file.  I also checked all my XML files to make sure there were any spaces before.

Comment: Aha!  I found this tutorial which I followed earlier: http://iamrookie.com/blog/159/add-custo-field-in-newsletter-module-magento.html  That worked for my forms that post to http://sites.dev/en/newsletter/subscriber/new/ but not for the form that I added in my post.

Comment: @Jonathan please tell me you haven't followed this tutorial. There is no need to copy core files (in fact you could even rewrite controllers). In this case, a simple observer (like the one you have put in place) should be way enough.

Comment: @Mayers Sorry, I have.  :(  Should I undo it?  Is it what is causing me all the problems?

Comment: I would say it doesn't help. Never manipulate core files, it's a very bad idea (it's quick but it will just cause more problems). Regarding your issue, I would temporarily disable all your other modules, revert to the default theme, and give it a try. As I said, just tried on a 1.9 install, and it worked first time (I literally copied the code you have listed above)